# Center of split extension of groups of co prime orders

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

Let $G = A \rtimes B,$ where $A$ is a finite $p$-group and $B$ is a finite $p'$ group. When can we say that $Z(G) \subseteq A?$

For example the center of the group $C_3 \rtimes C_4$ is $C_2$ and hence $Z(G)$ is not a subgroup of $C_3.$ Thus in this case $Z(G)$ is not contained in $A.$ I wanted to ask that under what conditions on $A$ and $B,$ does this hold true. Is there some nice reference where I can read more details about the general theory behind it.

Comment: Please don't repost [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4418710/104041).

Answer (score 2):

Writing $G= A \rtimes B$ does not define $G$ uniquely. For example, you cannot talk about "the group $C_3 \rtimes C_4$", because there are two groups with that structure, and their centres are $C_2$ and $C_4$.

To define $G = A \rtimes_\phi B$, you need to specify a homomorphism $\phi: B \to {\rm Aut}(A)$. Then the condition for $Z(G) \le A$ is that $\ker \phi$ is trivial.

Comment: Yes, actually I was trying to look for the subgroup of automorphism group of $p$-groups, which is of order co-prime to p and acts faithfully on $A.$ From there I reached the conclusion that if $Z(G) \cap B$ is trivial then the $p^{'}$ group $B$ acts faithfully on $p$-group $A.$ That is why I want to know that when $Z(G) \subseteq A?$

Comment: If the center contains $C_4$, then the center is all of $G$: it's a direct product of abelian groups.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Yes that's right, but the point I was making was that there are two possible semidirect products, so you need to specify the action in order to define the group.

Comment: @ Derek Holt. Thank you very much for your reply. I am only considering the non-abelian cases here. Like you just mentioned, if the action of B on A is faithful, then center of the group is a subgroup of the p-group A. I wanted to ask whether the center will be non-trivial or not. We know that center of a p-group is non-trivial, but here we just know that $Z(G) \subseteq Z(A)$.

Comment: @mathseeker I believe that I have answered your original question. Are you now asking a new question? There are examples in which $Z(G)$ is trivial and other examples where it is not. I am not convinced that asking "when is the center nontrivial?" means much here.

Comment: Yes my original question has already been answered by you and its clear to me now. Thanks.

Comment: I guess it is $\phi\colon B\to\operatorname {Aut}(A)$, not "$\operatorname {Aut}(G)$".

Comment: @fitzcarraldo Yes, thanks, I have corrected that!